# Is there a way to backup or export Azure IOT components?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-suite

I've got a large Azure IOT Suite implementation and I'd like to back it up or export the various jobs/components for safe keeping. We had a few instances where someone deleted something incorrectly and it took some time to recreate it.
Thanks!
   Nick

Comment: You customized the Remote Monitoring or Predictive Maintenance solutions?

Comment: We did not. We custom built it from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally figured this out. With the new Resource Manager, you can click on the "Automation Script" and it will build out the ARM template that can be used to recreate the resources / settings as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using azureiotsuite.com to deploy your Azure IoT suite?

Microsoft provides with an alternative approach of deploying it locally, and you can also customize and extend the solution to meet your specific requirements.

See to this [repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-remote-monitoring) for more details.

Comment: We are not. I'm aware of that approach, but we have updated the config of the items (inputs/outputs, etc) and we'd like to back that up so we have it for later.

Answer (score 0):

Use a DevOps approach i.e. script all the components and maintain the scripts in GitHub or some other version control tool.

Unfortunately, support for reverse engineering existing components is very limited.